# spring compatibility with javax servlet

Tags: java, spring

How to understand the compatible versions of javax-servlet-api and hibernate for each version of spring. Most times, when I upgrading the spring version, I am getting error due to version incompatibility of javax-servlte-api and hibernate.

Comment: try to use most updated version of all of them.

Comment: Generally the [New in Spring x.y](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.0) includes hints of the versions or at least the API versions. There is generally a minimum version and more features are available when using newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recently looking for similar info and stumbled on [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework) links which give some pointers/minimum dependencies while migrating from earlier version of Spring to later versions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using Spring Boot directly, but a decent way to do this would be to look at the dependencies defined by Spring Boot for the version you are using. Spring Boot includes a `spring-boot-dependencies` project, which does this.

You can look through the history of the dependencies at GitHub:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

Just find the version which uses the core Spring version you are on and take note of the versions.